# How to validate unicode characters?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, unicode, forms

I have one registration form, I don't want people to register login username with unicode characters. How can i put server side validation PHP + client side validation javascript or jquery.

Please kindly help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well do you mean outside of normal ASCII range?

You could implement one of the many `seemsLikeUtf8()` function floating around on the net.

Or do a quick regular expression

```
if ( ! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i', $username)) {
   echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you realize this or not, but that pattern doesn't actually allow for UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @Peter The OP wanted to stop people registering using non standard characters I think. I'm not expert on UTF-8 (though learning) so feel free to point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Wow, I managed to totally gloss over the "don't" in his question.  Anyway, for the records, PCRE patterns can by made UTF-8 aware with the `u` flag (little u, not big U)

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I didn't know there was the little *u* flag. Just knew about the default ungreedy *U*. +1 to your comment because I learned something :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression would do:

```
if (!username.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_+]+$)) {
   alert("invalid username");
}
```

This will check that the username contains only the characters a-z (upper and lower case), the digits 0-9, '_' and '+'. If you want to extend it to allow other characters, you'll just need to look up a bit more about [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

On the server-side, you'd do exactly the same thing, since PHP also supports [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).